# How to get individual file contents from ZipArchiveInputStream using Apache commons compress library

Tags: java, zip, apache-commons-compress

I have org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream Object, 
from which I can get each ArchiveEntry item and get the individual file's metadata. 
But I need to know the way to get each file's contents as Blob.

Using org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile it can be done, 
but ZipFile has constructors with physical or temporary File object or a file location.
I dont want to create a temporary File for this.

Even if there is a way to convert ZipArchiveInputStream  to ZipFile, it would solve 
the problem indirectly.

In short, my requirement is to read a Zip file from an InputStream/Blob and store individual Files as BLOB in Database.

FYI: I am using  org.apache.commons :: commons-compress :: 1.4.1

Any solutions/ideas/suggestions  are highly appreciated.

Cheers
Kum

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could use [standard java.util.zip.ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) - it has a constructor for InputStream. you can use `getNextEntry()` / `closeEntry()` to iterate through entries and `read()` to obtain decompressed data.